# Rebuild MySQL database on AWS EC2 from ESB volumes

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

We have inadvertently terminated an EC2 instance on our AWS account. The EC2 instance was launched from a Linux, MySQL AMI which is maintained and distributed by a third party.
It was ESB backed, so we still have the volumes available to us. We are hoping the volumes hold the MySQL data. We are now in the process of rebuilding the EC2 instance and attach the volumes to restore the environment. My questions are as follows:

1. The AMI that we have is pretty old. If we launch a new instance from it, then will it have all the patches for Linux and MySQL applied to it?
2. If we launch a new instance and reattach the volumes to it, will the MySQL databases come up automatically or there needs to be additional steps that we need to perform in order to restore databases ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question. Don't use the AMI installation of MySQL for recovery purpose. Install a fresh one instead.

For second. Once you have the fresh setup of the MySQL ready, stop the service attach and mount the volume (take another precautionary backup of the datadir) and then update the mysql_datadir in the my.cnf file to point to the directory in the volume that holds your data. Once done, restart the service and that should bring the data back